# What happens to wages when you go bankrupt? (England)

Tags: united-kingdom, salary, bankruptcy

I am having a difficult time keeping up with my payments during the pandemic after being furloughed since March. I have contacted [StepChange](https://www.stepchange.org/) and they have advised me that the best course of action for my situation was to fill up for bankruptcy. I'm supposed to come out of furlough next week but I am employed full time. I rent privately and don't own a car. They recommended that before I fill up for bankruptcy I open a basic current account as my current one will be frozen and it will get difficult to get one once I am bankrupt. I have done so and open another CC account. They also said that I should stop paying my creditors now (non-essential bills) and write to them explaining my situation and save as much as I can. It is worth mentioning that I am not in arrears on any of my bills at the moment but once I paid all my expenses I have nothing left and live off my credit card.

My questions are:

1. **What will happen to my wages when I go bankrupt**? Should I tell HR to pay my salary to my new current account or should I wait for my appointment with the OR once my bankruptcy has been accepted?
2. **Is it legal stop paying my creditors** now and **save money** (if there is any left) since I will fill up for bankruptcy soon?

Country: England (UK)

Comment: Unless your wages *exactly* met your expenses before furlough, I'm not sure I see the wisdom of declaring bankruptcy *now*, just before you return to work.

Comment: I am not in the UK, but I see two red flags in their advice: stop paying bills, open an account to put funds to "protect"  it from being frozen. How much do you trust this organization?

Comment: @chepner my wages will go down when I start again, and the interest on my credits cards during the past 6 months will make it difficult to realistically keep up paying off my debts.

Comment: StepChange is a major debt charity in the UK so their advice is definitely legit.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep StepChange is a very reputable Debt Charity authorised and regulated by the FCA.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: It sounds like the advice is to switch to a cheaper account type, while you still can. That makes sense.